# How can I auto run and send (to file server or email) crystal reports on the cheap?

Tags: crystalreports

Trying to find a way to email daily reports on the cheap to some folks.  Need them to run same select statement and fire out a report from an access database.  Would work if the users ran them on an as need basis themselves too.

I tried Groff Automation Crystal Delivery but it hardly functions.  Also tried ChristianSteven Crystal Report Delivery, but its only a 30 day trial.

I have crystal server XI installed as well as Infoview.  I'm new to crystal and I don't see a way to allow infoview to let users run reports - I can only run them and upload results myself, and the data is not dynamic.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

It's free!